# Loop through a hash and save to a different row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got below hash

```
=> {"email"=>["old@email.com", "new@email.com"],
 "name"=>["some name", "stupid name"],
 "updated_at"=>[Fri, 28 Aug 2020 15:01:53 UTC +00:00, Mon, 31 Aug 2020 20:18:26 UTC +00:00]}
```

which first value of each key e.g. `["email"][0]` is an `old_data` and the second value of each key e.g. `["name"][1]` is a `new_data`

From the data above I want to create a CSV file with headers of Old Data and New Data and with desired structure:

```
Old Data                   New Data
{ email: old@email.com }   { email: new@email.com}
{ name: “some name” }      { name: "no name" }
```

I was trying to use below code:

```
LOG_HEADERS = ['Old Data', 'New Data'].freeze

  CSV.generate(col_sep: ';', headers: LOG_HEADERS, encoding: 'UTF-8') do |csv|
    hash.each do |v|
      old_data_value = v.map { |k, v| k + ": #{v[0]}" }
      new_data_value = v.map { |k, v| k + ": #{v[1]}" }

      csv << [old_data_value,
              new_data_value]
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm getting an array with below structure:

```
Old Data                                     New Data
["email: old@email.com", "name: some name"]  ["email: new@email.com", "name: stupid name"]
```

How to change it to hash with the structure described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CSV.generate(col_sep: ';', headers: LOG_HEADERS, encoding: 'UTF-8', write_headers: true) do |csv|
  hsh.each do |key,value|
    row = []
    value.each do |v|
      row << "{#{key}: #{v}}"
    end
    csv << row
  end
end
```